# Android reusable view and OnClickListener

Tags: include, onclicklistener

I am trying to implement a reusable view and create an OnClickListener that will work for all classes. My code is below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.layout1).findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.layout1).findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.layout1).findViewById(R.id.button3);        

        applyListener(layout,listener);
        applyListener(layout,listener);
        applyListener(layout,listener);

    }

    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {    
            switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.button1:
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ONE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, P2.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:  
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TWO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, P3.class);
                     startActivity(intent2);
                 break; 
            case R.id.button3:  
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "THREE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, P4.class);
                 startActivity(intent3);
             break; 
                 }  
            }

        private Context getContext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

     }; 





        private static void applyListener(View child, OnClickListener listener) {
            if (child == null)
                return;

            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                applyListener((ViewGroup) child, listener);
            }
            else if (child != null) {
                if(child.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                    child.setOnClickListener(listener);
                }     
                if(child.getId() == R.id.button2) {
                    child.setOnClickListener(listener);
                }
                if(child.getId() == R.id.button3) {
                    child.setOnClickListener(listener);
                }



            }
        }

        private static void applyListener(ViewGroup parent, OnClickListener listener) {
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
                if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    applyListener((ViewGroup) child, listener);
                } else {
                    applyListener(child, listener);
                }
            }
        }


}
```

The problem is that once it moves out of the MainActivty, it will crash as soon as I press any button. I am sure it is to do with the line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, P2.class);
```

and I think the problem is related to the fact that it is referencing a class that is not active eg MainActivity.this. I have tried replacing MainActivity.this with:

```
this
```

and

```
getContext()
```

and

```
getBaseContext()
```

but they do not work.

I have also tried

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.APANEL.P2.class");
```

but this does not work either.

I am sure the applyListener method is being implemented properly as the buttons are all children and are therefore being implemented using the method:

```
private static void applyListener(ViewGroup parent, OnClickListener listener)
```

I have read the android documentation and every post I can find, but I cannot seem to find a working solution.

Any help would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by doing the following:

In the MainActivity class I created the method:

```
public void setup(){

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.layout1).findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.layout1).findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.layout1).findViewById(R.id.button3);                            
        applyListener(layout,listener);

    }
```

Then, all classes that re-use the view eg display the button panel must extend MainActivity, and in the `onCreate()` method, they implement the method `setup()`

To summarise, it was nothing to do with the Intent, but was to do with the fact that in the subsequent classes, the listeners were not set up.